# How to call a real method from a mocked class using jmockit

Tags: java, junit, jmockit

Say I have a class `MockLoginHelper` that I mocked using `jmockit`. And I would like to change the behaviour of one of the method `getSDKConfig`. Inside this method I would like to call the original `LoginHelper.relogin`. My eclipse thinks `relogin();` below is undefined. So, how do I call a real method from a mocked class?

```
class MockLoginHelper extends MockUp<LoginHelper> {
    @Tested
    private SDKConfiguration config;

    @Mock
    public SDKConfiguration getSDKConfig() {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Mocked " + this.getClass().getSimpleName());
        if (config == null) {
            try {
                relogin();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("failed to relogin");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return config;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way in JMockit to call the original method from a mocked method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/357121/is-there-a-way-in-jmockit-to-call-the-original-method-from-a-mocked-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java compiler rightly thinks that `relogin` method is not in your mocked class because `MockLoginHelper` extends `MockUp` class, not `LoginHelper` class. You have two options. If you want to actually call real implementation of your `LoginHelper` then you need to instantiate a new one:

```
class MockLoginHelper extends MockUp<LoginHelper> {
    @Tested
    private SDKConfiguration config;

    @Mock
    public SDKConfiguration getSDKConfig() {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Mocked " + this.getClass().getSimpleName());
        if (config == null) {
            try {
                LoginHelper helper = new LoginHelper();
                helper.relogin();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("failed to relogin");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return config;
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you have an option of doing a mock implementation and calling that mock:

```
class MockLoginHelper extends MockUp<LoginHelper> {
    @Tested
    private SDKConfiguration config;

    @Mock
    public void relogin() {}

    @Mock
    public SDKConfiguration getSDKConfig() {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Mocked " + this.getClass().getSimpleName());
        if (config == null) {
            try {
                relogin();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("failed to relogin");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return config;
    }
}
```