# How do I invoke a real function in my unit tests with jMockit?

Tags: java, unit-testing, jmockit

I have read this post: [Is there a way in JMockit to call the original method from a mocked method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357121/is-there-a-way-in-jmockit-to-call-the-original-method-from-a-mocked-method)

but the recommend solution throws a NPE. Here is my source

```
 static Map<String, Boolean> detectDeadlocks(int timeInSeconds) {
    final Map<String, Boolean> deadlockMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
        // I want to check if the method is run.
        **deadlockMap.put("deadlock", isDeadlockAfterPeriod());**
      }

    }, timeInSeconds * 1000);
    return deadlockMap;
  }
```

I want to be able to invoke `isDeadlockAfterPeriod` in my unit test. This is a static method that I have mocked in my unit tests.

My unit test code

```
  @Test
  public void testDetectDeadlocks() throws Exception {
    new Expectations(){
      {
           // Called from inside the TimerTask.
           ClassUnderTest.isDeadlockAfterPeriod();
           result = false;
      }
    };

    TimerMockUp tmu = new TimerMockUp();
    Deadlocks.detectDeadlocks(0);
    Assert.assertEquals(1, tmu.scheduleCount);
  }

  class TimerMockUp extends MockUp<Timer> {
    int scheduleCount = 0;

    @Mock
    public void $init() {}

    @Mock
    public void schedule(Invocation invocation, TimerTask task, long delay) {
      scheduleCount ++;
      invocation.proceed(); // Trying to call the real method, but this throws a NPE.
    }
  }
```

Error stack trace is seen with JUnit in Eclipse.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.myproject.test.DeadlocksTest$TimerMockUp.schedule(DeadlocksTest.java:78)
    at com.myproject.test.Deadlocks.detectDeadlocks(Deadlocks.java:41)
    at com.myproject.test.DeadlocksTest.testDetectDeadlocks(DeadlocksTest.java:86)
```

Comment: For static resources, You can use PowerMock API to mocking.

Comment: Could you add the NPE's stacktrace to have any clue on what is actually `null`.

Comment: @PrathibhaChiranthana I am using jMockit library.

Comment: @dpr Updated post.

Comment: Actually I think you method's design is not very testing friendly. I'd create a method that creates the `Runnable` for the `TimerTask`. This way you can easily unit test the `Runnable` without messing around with mocking too much.

Comment: @Kartik Static Resources can't be accessed through the object mocking. You have to use PowerMock API as per my understanding.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44054243/powermockito-mock-single-static-method-and-return-object-inside-another-static-m?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @PrathibhaChiranthana jMockit allows you to test static code. Secondly, if I use Powermock, I can not use code coverage tools like Jacoco because the PowerMock agent messes with the instrumentation agent.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are also faking the Timer's constructor (and not only the `schedule` method).

By doing so, you are preventing the correct initialization of the Timer, and as you are then using its real implementation, it fails to do so.

Specifically (with the sources I have), you are preventing the initialization of its `queue` field, which is used on its `mainLoop()` method (the one that will call to your `TimerTask.run()`).

Also, you need to do partial mocking of `Deadlocks` class, as I understand that `isDeadlockAfterPeriod` is also a static method for the said class.

I'll leave you here a working example:

**Deadlocks.class**

```
public class Deadlocks {

    public static Map<String, Boolean> detectDeadlocks(int timeInSeconds) {
        final Map<String, Boolean> deadlockMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        new Timer()// this will be the real constructor
                .schedule( // this will be first mocked, then really executed
                        new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                deadlockMap.put("deadlock", isDeadlockAfterPeriod()); // this will put false after the mock is called
            }

        }, timeInSeconds * 1000);

        return deadlockMap;
    }

    public static Boolean isDeadlockAfterPeriod() {
        return true; // this, we will mock it
    }

}
```

**Test class**

```
@RunWith(JMockit.class)
public TestClass{
    @Test
    public void testDetectDeadlocks() throws Exception {
        new Expectations(Deadlocks.class){ // do partial mocking of the Deadlock class
            {
                // Called from inside the TimerTask.
                Deadlocks.isDeadlockAfterPeriod();
                result = false;
            }
        };

        // prepare the fake
        TimerMockUp tmu = new TimerMockUp();

        // execute the code
        Map<String, Boolean> result = Deadlocks.detectDeadlocks(0);

        // assert results
        assertThat(tmu.scheduleCount, is(1));
        assertThat(result.size(), is(1));
        assertThat(result.get("deadlock"), is(false));
    }

    class TimerMockUp extends MockUp<Timer> {
        int scheduleCount = 0;

        @Mock
        public void schedule(Invocation invocation, TimerTask task, long delay) {
            scheduleCount ++;

            invocation.proceed();
        }
    }
}
```

In general, be very careful when faking constructors, as you may leave the instances in an inconsistent state.